# onchange() Method in openerp 7 is not Working

Tags: python, xml, odoo

Here is my python file.

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv

select_list=[('SL01','SL01'),('SL02','SL02'),('SL03','SL03')]
select_sub_list=[('EDS01','EDS01'),('EDS02','EDS02'),('EDS03','EDS03')]


class laser_products(osv.osv):

  _inherit = "product.product"

  _columns = {
    'laser_product_select': fields.selection(select_list,'Main category'),
    'laser_sub_product_select': fields.selection(select_sub_list,'Sub category'),
    'temp':fields.char("Product Code")
  }

  def onchange_laser_product_select(self,cr,uid,ids,laser_product_select,context=None):
     temp=str(laser_product_select)
     return temp   

laser_products()
```

Here is my XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
  <data>
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="laser_product_project">
        <field name="name">product.normal.form</field>
        <field name="model">product.product</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_normal_form_view" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">

                <field name='list_price' position="after">
                    <field name="laser_product_select" on_change="onchange_laser_product_select(laser_product_select,context)"/>
                        <field name="laser_sub_product_select" />
                        <field name="temp"/>           
                </field>

        </field>
    </record>
  </data>
</openerp>
```

I want to change the product code field to SL01 when I select main category field but after selection it is not showing in product code field also it is not showing any error too.

Please provide me the correct Code or tell me where i am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your *onchange()* method with following:

```
def onchange_laser_product_select(self, cr, uid, ids, laser_product_select, context=None):

    value = {}

    if laser_product_select:
       value['temp'] = str(laser_product_select)

       #generic formate to update value onchange
       #value['field_name'] = field_value

    return {'value': value}
```